# AVPlayer Works on Simulator, but not on device

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

```
  playerItem=[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.radio.com.lk/y-fm/"]]];
  player=[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] ;
  [player play];
```

It's working on Simulator but in the device, it's not. In the console,
I have the following error:

> CredStore - performQuery - Error copying matching creds. 
>   Error=-25300, query={
>       class = inet;
>       "m_Limit" = "m_LimitAll";
>       "r_Attributes" = 1;
>       sync = syna; }

Can anyone help me with a clue?

Comment: [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&activationError];

Have you added this code in Appdelegate?

Comment: Hi Sambit -no I did not add those. should I add these two lines?  --> 

[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES
AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeact‌​ivation error:&activationError];

Comment: Can you tell me to where should I add that?

Comment: Sorry mate, I got same error after putting that :(

Comment: check my answer. it may help you

Comment: is it a server issue  where video stored?

Answer (score 2):

Please add below code in your app delegate. It may help you

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:&activationError];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&setCategoryError];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
}
```

Comment: Could you please explain your code? What is the reason for the error? I have the same error but for totally different code. Until now I have no idea where to search for the reason... thanks!

Comment: is it solution for above asked question? why people voted up this answer?

Answer (score 1):

My answer is for you

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
@property (nonatomic,strong)AVAudioPlayer *player;
- (IBAction)actionPlay:(id)sender;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize player;
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)actionPlay:(id)sender {
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:yourURL];
    AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playVideo play];
}
```